# How to configure map reduce plugin in eclipse from windows(Hadoop installed in Linux server)

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to connect to hadoop clusters from a windows
machine that is not a part of hadoop cluster..
Bascially we installed hadoop on linux server machines.. so no GUI is
available. So for that reason, what we are trying to do is to run eclipse
with hadoop eclipse plugin on windows machine.. and trying to runn code from
windows machine.

I am not able to figure out how I can run map reduce
programs from this windows machine to the hadoop master node..

Answer (score 0):

*You can have a Developing environment  of Map-Reduce In windows by installing*  **Cygwin**

---

---

You will require :

1. *Cygwin*
2. *Configure ssh daemon*
3. *Start SSH daemon*
4. *Setup authorization keys*
5. *Download hadoop 0.19.1*

---

---

[For More Details Please go through this link](http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html)